# Face detection return value without face

Tags: python, arrays, detection, face-detection, haar-classifier

I' using haar cascade for face detection

```
faces_haar = face_cascade.detectMultiScale(image, scaleFactor=1.3,  minNeighbors=4, minSize=(30, 30), flags=cv2.CASCADE_SCALE_IMAGE)
```

and i save the face in this variables

```
(x, y, w, h) = faces_haar[0]
```

and in my fucntion i return

```
return image[y:y+h, x:x+w] , faces_haar[0]
```

when he dont find any face gives me the error  "IndexError: tuple index out of range"
because i dont have any face.

How i can return only when he find some face?

Comment: ok i already know, i can do  "  if len(faces_haar ) == 0:
                                                         return -1, -1

Comment: I would rather return None than -1.

Comment: more popular `if not faces_haar: return None`. OR you should do `if faces_haar: return image[y:y+h, x:x+w] , faces_haar[0]` and then it will automatically run `return None`

Answer (score 0):

You should use `if` to check if list is not empty

```
if faces_haar:
   (x, y, w, h) = faces_haar[0]
   return image[y:y+h, x:x+w] , faces_haar[0]
```

and it will automatically run `return None`